# Oracle Query returns no rows selected error

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I need help with solving this query .  **List employee details for the employees who work at the same cinema as the employee Joe Bloggs who has empno 77.**
What have I done wrong for it to return (No rows selected).

```
   SELECT *
   FROM Employee
   WHERE Cinema_no = ( SELECT Cinema_no 
   FROM Employee
   WHERE First_name = 'Joe' AND Surname = 'Bloggs')
   ORDER BY Surname ASC ;
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong. Did you run the subquery by itself? Does it return any rows? If not, try `where empno = 77` instead of filtering on names; does *that* return anything? Perhaps one of the names is misspelled?

Comment: @mathguy I tried what you said and it worked by showing 8 different employees who work at the same cinema, so I'm not sure why it didn't run with the names. The only problem is it also includes Joe bloggs as one of those employees . I was hoping to filter him out and ONLY include the other 7 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming all table names and column names are correct then, to debug you must ensure the subquery works first. Run it separately, for some "trail and error" debugging

```
SELECT
    *
FROM Employee
WHERE First_name = 'Joe'
AND Surname = 'Bloggs'
```

Perhaps try LIKE? and/or with fewer conditions

```
SELECT
    *
FROM Employee
WHERE First_name LIKE 'Joe%'
-- AND Surname LIKE 'Bloggs%' 
-- AND empno = 77
```

remove the -- if the one above is working

Once that is fully working then the balance of your query should meet your objective.

---

```
SELECT *
FROM Employee
WHERE Cinema_no = (
   SELECT Cinema_no 
   FROM Employee
   WHERE First_name = 'Joe' AND Surname = 'Bloggs'
   and empno = 77
   )
and empno <> 77
ORDER BY Surname ASC ;
```

Comment: Thanks , I tried the subquery it didn't work , so i just created the test data again. And then it worked with the query i used above. Even though the test data was the exactly the same from the one i deleted.

Comment: mmmm, ok, bit weird, but unable to offer any insight on that :)

Comment: Thee result showed 8 employees including Joe bloggs working at the same cinema. Is there a way to filter out Joe bloggs so it will only show the other 7 ? . Or is it fine including him with them.

Comment: add `and empno <> 77`  in the outer where clause? see edit above

Comment: as to should the answer be 8 or 7 in the result - depends entirely on how you read the question

Comment: Gives me error when i add `and empno <> 77 `I guess i'll leave it how it is , unless you have a alternative.

Comment: if `and empno = 77` works in the subquery there is NO REASON why it would not work in the outer query must be some other problem (*ps. if you get an error tell us EXACTLY what the error message is - my crystal ball is foggy today.*)

Comment: I fixed the error it said " invalid identifier " . The reason as to why it was wrong was it should of been  `emp_no` i copied your  `empno`. The result is perfect now. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what your data looks like, but replace the '=' with the keyword 'in'
This will come in handy for future queries that are using this logic.
I have made the change and added the code below.

```
   SELECT *
   FROM Employee
   WHERE Cinema_no in ( SELECT Cinema_no 
   FROM Employee
   WHERE First_name = 'Joe' AND Surname = 'Bloggs')
   ORDER BY Surname ASC ;
```